# fixed vector as template parameter on c++ class

Tags: c++, templates

I want to create a class like this:

```
template<std::vector<char> ID>
class test
{
      std::vector<char> m_id=ID;
 public:
      std::vector<char> getID()
      { 
           return ID;
      }
}
```

and then use it such as this:

```
typedef test1234 test<{'1','2','3','4','5'}>
test1234 t1;
std::cout <<t1.getID()<<std:;endl;
```

How can I do this?

The idea is that I can define several classes with the same functionality, but different ID. I don't want to pass the ID as construction parameters (I know how to do that way!).

I am using VS 2013.

Comment: You can [read about the requirements for non-type template parameters](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters). `std::vector` does not fulfill them.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Is there any way that I can simulate this with say a buffer or similar types?

Comment: You can use `template <char... Args>` in modern C++, but I don't think VS 2013 can handle that.

Comment: @nwp can you provide more information?

Comment: Basically what Edgar Rokyan wrote.

Comment: why Edgar Rokyan removed his answer?

Comment: I think it is because you specified VS 2013 in the question and the answer doesn't compile in VS 2013. If you are willing to change your compiler it makes sense to undelete that answer. Are you?

Comment: How can I undelete the answer?

Comment: You can't. Edgar Rokyan (or a moderator) would need to do that. I will leave a comment and maybe he will do it.

Comment: @nwp I have just undeleted it.

Comment: @EdgarRokyan Thanks for help. The solution is good even it is not working on VS2013. I decided to use VS2015 for this reason!

Answer (score 0):

If you change your problem from "how to initialize a vector with template parameter" (to which there is no solution with VS2013) to "how to have different constructors parametrised with template arguments" then I have a solution. You should define array of strings and pass a subscript for that array, that would sove it:

```
std::string initializers[]={{'1','2','3','4','5'},"Hello moto"};

template<int ID>
class test
{
      std::vector<char> m_id{initializers[ID].begin(),initializers[ID].end()};
 public:
      std::vector<char> getID()
      { 
           return  std::vector<char> {initializers[ID].begin(),initializers[ID].end()};
      }
};
```

Which will make following valid:

```
int main()
{
    typedef  test<1> test1234;
    test1234 t1;
    std::cout <<t1.getID()[0] <<std::endl; // you obviously do not have stream output operator for vector
}
```

Add `const`s to your taste and probably encapsulate `initializers` if you want.